# How to translate “host an event”?

Tags: translation

I’m looking for a translation of the word *host* in the sense of hosting a poker evening or maybe a party. Specifically, I want a word for the person who runs a gaming session in the online Esperanto congress [Retoso](https://retoso2021.tejo.org/).

I guess the usual word to translate *host* is *gastigi*, but that doesn’t seem appropriate in this case because no-one is a guest and they aren’t being accepted into someone’s home.

Another word in English could be *facilitate* which John Wells translates as *faciligi*. That doesn’t seem like the right word at all in this context.

I’m not really sure of the right word in English either to be honest. In French there is *animer* which seems ideal. If I use Google translate I get this:

> Je vais animer une soirée de jeux de société.
> ➝
> Mi aranĝos tabulludvesperon.

This doesn’t seem right either because it gives the impression that you are just organising it. I want to capture the notion that you are also going to be talking during the event and telling everyone what to do like a gameshow host.

Comment: Ĉu partoprenanto de evento ne estas _ia_ gasto, eĉ se la evento ne estas en la hejmo de la gastiganto? Isn't an event participant _some_ kind of guest, even when the event doesn't take place at the host's home?

Answer (score 1):

Gastigi signifas ankaŭ *organizi eventon en kiu partoprenos vizitantoj*.

> La urbo Montrealo, Kanado, devus gastigi la ĉi-jaran Universalan Kongreson de Esperanto ([UN](https://www.un.org/development/desa/indigenouspeoples/wp-content/uploads/sites/19/2020/08/Indigenous-Peoples-Day-2020-Universal-Esperanto-Association.pdf))

> piedpilk-stadiono de la gastiganta urbo (Monato)

> Fondita cele al gastigo de IJK en 1992, KEJO poste malpli viglis. (Monato)

Kaj tiel plu.

Gastiganto estas do ankaŭ ia organizanto.

Vi ankaŭ povus rekte uzi `organizi` kaj `organizanto` sed senteblas pli intima la aranĝo kiam ĝin prizorgas gastiganto (kio cetere evidentigas la ĉeeston de vizitantoj) ol kiam ĝin prizorgas organizanto.

Comment: I perhaps didn’t phrase the question very well, but I want a word that isn’t necessarily organising the event, but being the person that asks questions to the other participants like a gameshow host. I feel like _gastigi_ is just a passive thing about providing a space for people to be during a certain time. The event could even be _organised_ by someone else, and that person could also pick the person that is going to run the event during the time slot.

Comment: For me _gastigi_ is not that passive, but ok, you want a term more like a ceremony master, _estro de ceremonio_ or eh _ceremoniulo_, Note, no verb in [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#ceremonio_kd).

Answer (score 0):

Why not *gastigi*? One for instance *gastigas retejojn* which does not include that any person physically visits somewhere. If you want to be more precise, add something about the event, for instance *gastigi ĉe evento*.

Comment: Yes, I guess that makes sense, but it still feels much more like a passive thing where you just provide a place for them to be during some time. I want a word to represent what happens when you participate in the activity and ask questions to the other participants, like a game show host. It doesn’t feel like _gastigi_ captures that sense.